# How to skip to a specific time in css-animations by seconds?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

is there any way to skip to specific time in css animation?
for example: if we have a div moving from left to right in 10 seconds, user change time to 5 and animation jumps to second 5 and continues playing.

Comment: You cannot change the CSS animation phase directly. However you can modify the keyframe CSS rules, but that might be a little tricky: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `animation-delay` will do exactly that.
When you change it to negative values, it will jump forward.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.number');
selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('.some-div');
  result.style.animationDelay = `${event.target.value}s`;
});
```

```css
.some-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-delay: 0;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="some-div"></div>
<input type="number" class="number" />
<br/>
change the value in the input
```

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag and [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) tag do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.